# Hidden files on NAS system (Synology DiskStation DS413j). How to recover space?

Tags: nas

We have had our Synology replaced with a newer, larger capacity one. I would like to re-purpose this one : Synology DiskStation DS413j for another purpose.  However, I cant see to clean the backups off from it. I dont see anything. Is there some setting that might hide it?

- Volume 1 (Normal) - 6.25 TB
- Used Capacity: 5.22 TB
- Available Capacity" 1.03 TB

storage pool 1 = 4 drives

It has no shared folders.  Yet, I cant see anything on the volume/drives. What am i missing? How do I recover the space on this DiskStation?

see attached screenshots

[image: Clean up]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's stuff still in the recycle bin? Look into the #recycle folders of your nas shares.  Or follow this https://synoguide.com/2019/02/12/empty-all-recycle-bins-on-your-synology-at-once/

Comment: No not in Recycle Bin

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to just reformat the drives?  Re-create the volume?

Or perhaps all you need to do is empty the recycle bin?  If the option is turned on and you simply deleted files, they will end up there.  Look for stuff in the #recycle folder of you shares, or follow this [link](https://synoguide.com/2019/02/12/empty-all-recycle-bins-on-your-synology-at-once/) to clear it out via the DSM.

Comment: Actually, what I did was do a factory reset - which ultimately deleted all data. I was hoping not heaving to do that, but I did it anyways. Didnt take long to reset it back up as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Never did figure out where the files were, but I figured out how to do a factory reset and it erased all data and Now after setting up from scratch, i have all the capacity back.

Answer (score 0):

if you ssh into the NAS you will see a bunch of hidden files and directories starting with @ sign.

Some of these are to support cloudstation (worst backup solution ever) etc.